# Parsing a folder moving files depending on file name

Tags: file, parsing, batch-file, dos

I am trying to create a batch file.

It should let specify a source and destination folder. The source folder will be parsed and depending on part of the file name the file will be moved to the destination folder. There will be multiple files in the source folder to be parsed.

The files will be something like `file-1-tmp.txt,  file-2-tmp.txt, file-3-tmp.txt etc.` 
I looked at using the FOR /F command using tokens and delims of - - but can't get it to recourse all of the files in the folder

If the file has -1- it will be moved to destination if a file has -2- it will be moved to another destination.

ps: Please help before I loose all my hair

Answer (score 2):

Can you just do multiple commands, one for each type of file?:

```
for %%i in (*-1-*.*) do move "%%i" dir1\.
for %%i in (*-2-*.*) do move "%%i" dir2\.
for %%i in (*-3-*.*) do move "%%i" dir3\.
...etc...
```

**UPDATE**

Based on @Andriy M's suggestion, a simpler approach would be:

```
for %%n in (1 2 3 <...etc...>) do move *-%%n-*.* dir%%n\.
```

Comment: Straightforward and clear, although, to be honest, I don't see why you need to use `FOR` loops for this. You could simply `move *-1-*.* dir1\ ` etc., couldn't you?

Comment: Good point. I was originally thinking about putting all of this within another `for` loop. (See edits.)

Comment: I like your second suggestion. If the numbers are consecutive, you could also use a `for /l` loop instead of a simple `for`: `for /l %%n in (1,1,10) do ...` (would iterate from 1 to 10 inclusive). Of course, in both cases it is assumed that the destinations are based on the same numbers too. So it's a somewhat specific approach, although, if applicable, it would likely be more efficient than my "universal" loop.

Answer (score 1):

There may be various approaches to this problem.

For instance, you could use a separate command for every set of files that need to be moved to the same destination, like in [@Loadmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349287/297408).

A rather different approach would be to iterate over all the files, determining each one's destination as you go. The implementation of this approach might look like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%I IN ("D:\path\to\source\file-*-tmp.txt") DO (
  FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%C IN ("%%C") DO (
    IF %%C == 1 (
      MOVE %%I D:\path\to\destination\1
    ) ELSE IF %%C == 2 (
      MOVE %%I D:\path\to\destination\2
    ) ELSE IF ...
    ...
  )
)
```

That is, you iterate over the files stored in a specific folder and matching a specific mask using a simple `FOR` loop. In the loop body, you use another loop, a `FOR /F` one, to split the name and get to the part that determines the destination. Once you've got that part, you compare it individually to all possible values using a set of nested `IF` commands, and for each match you specify a `MOVE` command to place the file accordingly.

You could also modify the above script in a way that would allow you to specify destination paths more conveniently. In particular, you could prepare a set of variables containing all possible destination paths, at the beginning of the script. In the inner loop's body, instead of multiple `IF`s you would use just one that determines whether a "destination variable" corresponding to the extracted part exists. If it does, you just use the path stored in that variable to move the file to. Here's how this variation might be implemented:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "dest1=D:\path\to\destination\1"
SET "dest2=D:\path\to\destination\2"
...
FOR %%I IN ("D:\path\to\source\file-*-tmp.txt") DO (
  FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%C IN ("%%C") DO (
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    IF DEFINED dest%%C MOVE %%I !dest%%C!
    ENDLOCAL
  )
)
```